# Writing jquery static util methods

Tags: jquery

I understand the concept of extending the jquery.fn to place your custom functions on the prototype chain of a jquery object, but in my case some of my utils don't need to be attached to a selector.
I'm basically looking for a static method. So I wanted to know of any pitfalls of writing static methods directly on the jquery object as util methods.

Example:

```
jquery.myMethod = function(arg){
   ......
} 

$.myMethod("blabla");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you seem to realize, it is a good idea to not dump all your utility functions into the global namespace.  The less you can impact the global namespace, the better.  If you already have jQuery, then your choices for where to put them are:

1. As new methods on the jQuery object as: `jQuery.myUtil1()`, `jQuery.myUtil2()`.
2. As new methods under one object on the jQuery object as: `jQuery.jfUtils.myUtil1()`, `jQuery.jfUtils.myUtil2()`.
3. As new methods on one new global object (nothing to do with jQuery) as: `jfUtils.myUtil1()`, `jfUtils.myUtil2()`.

Option 2) seems better to me than option 1) because you lessen the chance of colliding with other jQuery functions though you do add an extra lookup for each function call.

Option 3) seems perfectly acceptable to me as it only adds one new item to the global namespace so as long as you make the name reasonably unique, you should be OK.

So, I'd think you could go with either option 2) or option 3).  Option 2) might be a little safer because you know the general extent of what is in that namespace, but either can work.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 so really its a matter of preference by the sounds of it, plus with directly adding it to the jquery object you really have to be more careful. Thats why I first checked the jquery.js file to make sure there were no methods of the same name that I would be adding. It just seems cleaner to add them directly to the jquery namesapce. But I also see the extra protection of adding another object directly to the jquery namespace to add your methods to.

Comment: +1 Definitely go with option 2. It really isn't that bad to write it as $.util.myMethod() and the protection will save you headaches down the line. Grouping common functions into namespaces is good practice in any languages. The exception being unless you decide to tie into jQuery's DOM manipulation chain.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't add static methods to jQuery. You don't gain anything by trying to.  The point of extending jQuery is so that jQuery objects found with query strings will have methods on them.  You're simply creating a global function, so just create a new top-level object to hold your functions.

Comment: Your statement is not quite true.  Putting methods on the jQuery object adds no new global namespace pollution or global namespace conflicts and as such can be better than dumping a whole bunch of new functions into the global namespace.  You would have to make sure you don't conflict with other jQuery functions, but you don't run any risk of colliding with anything else at the global level.

Comment: I don't see how one is better than the other: either you add a name to the global namespace, and hope that you don't collide with something there, or you add a new name to the jQuery object and hope you don't collide with something there. It's the same issue either way, but at least by adding a name to the global namespace you are owning your toplevel name, and not confusing the issue by making it look like something jQuery provides.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I pointed out the pros/cons of each.  It probably depends upon which namespace you think is better understood and less likely to have a conflict - the jQuery object namespace or the global namespace - no single right answer.  Either can work.  I was pointing out in my comment that one might consider adding jQuery utility functions to the jQuery object even though they aren't jQuery object methods.  There are other reasons to do so.

Comment: If your utility function itself is using jQuery features then it probably makes more sense to add it to the jQuery object so that you don't create a globally namespaced function which has a potentially unknown dependency on jQuery.