# it doesn't read my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i cannot get it read my own plugin *Miplugin*, im getting the following on the console:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined miscript.js?*

*Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'Miplugin' (index):39*

I included this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./miscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The plugin is in *miscript.js*, the errors are here:

```
function detect_nav() {
    if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6) {
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

The other:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
    $.Miplugin().Inicial();//here is the problem
//Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'Miplugin'
```

It run without any problem in another hosting. I use chrome

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) was removed in 1.9. Try reading the docs next time

Comment: I know, my problem is that the plugin _Miplugin_ doesn't get to be written.

Comment: The error will probably be preventing your plugin from being compiled and added into jQuery

Comment: Also, how are you registering your plugin? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541218/writing-jquery-static-util-methods for some better ideas

Comment: It used to work well in another hosting and localhost so the navigator is compiling it well.

Comment: Consider using a plugin such as [the JQuery Migrate plugin.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)  Also, would you include (paste or post a link to) miscript.js?

Comment: @Atutouato is so extense but here the basic structure:
`(function ($) {
        $.fn.Miplugin = function () {
           
            $.Miplugin = function (opciones) {
                $.ropc = $.extend({}, param, opciones);
    
                var Metodos = {
                    Inicial: function () {
                       
                    }
                };
                return Metodos;
            };
            $.Miplugin.musc_anterior = function () {

            };
            $.Miplugin.movPlaylist = function () {};
            return $.Miplugin;
        }();
    })(jQuery);`

Comment: @user2495207, I can't take a look at it today since it's so late, but I'll take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I deleted many fuctions from it that doesn't make sense but i supose the structure is the important thing in this case.

Comment: The internet was braking up when uploading the scripts files, i uploaded again and know goes well. Although they were there i supose were corrupted. Thanks